# in a multi structure xml -comparing values and updating the xml field

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, composite

I have the below xml

```
<Messages>
<Message1>
    <EmpLDU>
        <Row>
            <Emp_id>325132 </Emp_id>
            <Pay_Group>AUS_NI102</Pay_Group>
            <Date_from_ec>20170814</Date_from_ec>
            <Date_to_ec>20170816</Date_to_ec>           
            <Counter>1</Counter>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Emp_id>1 </Emp_id>
            <Pay_Group>AUS_NI102</Pay_Group>
            <Date_from_ec>20170720</Date_from_ec>
            <Date_to_ec>20170720</Date_to_ec>
            <Counter>1</Counter>
        </Row>
    </EmpLDU>
</Message1>
<Message2>
    <PayCalendar>
        <PayCalendar>       
            <toPayPeriod>
                <PayPeriod>
                    <PayCalendar_payGroup>AUS_NI102</PayCalendar_payGroup>
                    <payPeriodBeginDate>2016-08-01T00:00:00.000</payPeriodBeginDate>
                    <payPeriodEndDate>2016-08-31T00:00:00.000</payPeriodEndDate>
                    <payCheckIssueDate>2016-08-15T00:00:00.000</payCheckIssueDate>
                    <externalCode>1297</externalCode>
                </PayPeriod>
                <PayPeriod>
                    <PayCalendar_payGroup>AUS_NI102</PayCalendar_payGroup>
                    <payPeriodBeginDate>2016-07-01T00:00:00.000</payPeriodBeginDate>
                    <payPeriodEndDate>2016-07-31T00:00:00.000</payPeriodEndDate>
                    <payCheckIssueDate>2016-07-15T00:00:00.000</payCheckIssueDate>
                    <externalCode>1296</externalCode>
                </PayPeriod>
            </toPayPeriod>
        </PayCalendar>
        <PayCalendar>
            <toPayPeriod>
                <PayPeriod>
                    <PayCalendar_payGroup>ARE_M01</PayCalendar_payGroup>
                    <payPeriodBeginDate>2017-12-01T00:00:00.000</payPeriodBeginDate>
                    <payPeriodEndDate>2017-12-31T00:00:00.000</payPeriodEndDate>
                    <payCheckIssueDate>2017-12-25T00:00:00.000</payCheckIssueDate>
                    <externalCode>1237</externalCode>
                </PayPeriod>
                <PayPeriod>
                    <PayCalendar_payGroup>ARE_M01</PayCalendar_payGroup>
                    <payPeriodBeginDate>2017-11-01T00:00:00.000</payPeriodBeginDate>
                    <payPeriodEndDate>2017-11-30T00:00:00.000</payPeriodEndDate>
                    <payCheckIssueDate>2017-11-25T00:00:00.000</payCheckIssueDate>
                    <externalCode>1236</externalCode>
                </PayPeriod>
            </toPayPeriod>
        </PayCalendar>
    </PayCalendar>
    <Message2><Messages>
```

I need in output the below message

```
<EmpLDU>
        <Row>
            <Emp_id>325132 </Emp_id>
            <Date_from_ec>20170814</Date_from_ec>
            <Date_to_ec>20170816</Date_to_ec>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Emp_id>1 </Emp_id>
            <Date_from_ec>20170720</Date_from_ec>
            <Date_to_ec>20170720</Date_to_ec>
        </Row></EmpLDU>
```

Where the field Date_from_ec is updated in reference with the message 2 > PayPeriod node (one which have payCheckIssueDate existsing in the current month)
then if the payPeriodBeginDate is greator than the Date_from_ec then

> the value of Date_from_ec needs to be updated with  payPeriodBeginDate  else keep the existing value.

Similarly 
the field Date_from_ec is updated in reference with the message 2 > PayPeriod node (one which have payCheckIssueDate existsing in the current month)
then if the payPeriodBeginDate is less than the Date_to_ec then

> the value of Date_to_ec needs to be updated with  payPeriodEndDate  else keep the existing value.

I have developed the below code but no joys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn xdt">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"
    indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:variable name="Current_Date">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(), '[Y0001][M01][D01]')" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Current_MonthYear">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($Current_Date, 1, 6)" />
</xsl:variable>

<!-- template that matches the root node -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <EmpLDU>
        <xsl:for-each select="EmpLDU/Row[Pay_Group !='']">

            <xsl:variable name="v_Pay_Group" select="Pay_Group" />
            <xsl:variable name="v_Date_from_ec" select="Date_from_ec" />
            <xsl:variable name="v_Date_to_ec" select="Date_to_ec" />

            <Row>
                <Emp_id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Emp_id" />
                </Emp_id>
                <xsl:variable name="v_payPeriodBeginDate">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Messages/Message2/PayCalendar/PayCalendar[payGroup = $v_Pay_Group]">
                        <xsl:for-each select="toPayPeriod/PayPeriod">   
                            <xsl:variable name="v_payCheckIssueDate">
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(payCheckIssueDate, '[Y0001][M01][D01]')" />
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:variable name="v_payCheckIssue_MonthYear">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring($v_payCheckIssueDate, 1, 6)" />
                            </xsl:variable>

                            <xsl:if test="$Current_MonthYear = $v_payCheckIssue_MonthYear" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(payPeriodBeginDate, '[Y0001][M01][D01]')" />                          
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="v_payPeriodEndDate">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Messages/Message2/PayCalendar/PayCalendar[payGroup = $v_Pay_Group]">
                        <xsl:for-each select="toPayPeriod/PayPeriod">   
                            <xsl:variable name="v_payCheckIssueDate">
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(payCheckIssueDate, '[Y0001][M01][D01]')" />
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:variable name="v_payCheckIssue_MonthYear">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring($v_payCheckIssueDate, 1, 6)" />
                            </xsl:variable>

                            <xsl:if test="$Current_MonthYear = $v_payCheckIssue_MonthYear" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(payPeriodEndDate, '[Y0001][M01][D01]')" />                                    
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <Date_from_ec>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$v_Date_from_ec &lt; $v_payPeriodBeginDate">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$v_payPeriodBeginDate"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$v_Date_from_ec" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </Date_from_ec>
                <Date_to_ec>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$v_Date_to_ec &gt; $v_payPeriodEndDate">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$v_payPeriodEndDate"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$v_Date_to_ec" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </Date_to_ec>               
            </Row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </EmpLDU>
</xsl:template>
<!-- -->
```

Need your inputs.
Thanks

Comment: You might want to cut down the sample data to relevant data to answer the question. Is there any change in the date fields in the input snippet and the desired output snippet you have shown? I am not sure I notice a change in those fields.

Comment: Hello Martin, I have trimmed the question to utmost relevance. Yes that is the required feature - where  -The fields like Date_from_ec and Date_to_ec needs to be calculated based on the fields in xml -message2 . With My code I get the value for Date_from_ec but strangely the Date_to_ec is empty.

Comment: Where the field Date_from_ec is updated in reference with the message 2 > PayPeriod node (one which have payCheckIssueDate existsing in the current month)
then if the payPeriodBeginDate is greator than the Date_from_ec then
> the value of Date_from_ec needs to be updated with  payPeriodBeginDate  else keep the existing value.

Answer (score -1):

The XSLT code mentioned above works fine. There was a data issue.
Cheers,
Vicky

Comment: I don't think that  `<xsl:for-each select="/*[name()='Messages/Message2/PayCalendar/PayCalendar[payGroup = $v_Pay_Group]">` can work fine.

Comment: The above xpath is the original one, I have refined the query for the issue. I have updated the above code section. Thanks for the mention

Comment: It seems StackOverflow doesn't allow to change the vote just now, will try later.